# c# check if library/namespace/class exists (at compile time)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, exists, compile-time

I've written some code in c# that uses a library, but I want to share it and want it to work regardless of whether that library exists, 
basically I want to check in my code whether the library exists, and if it doesn't, I use alternate code to do what the library was supposed to do.

So how would you do that?

I thought maybe I could use Preprocessor Directives, but to be honest I have little experience with these and can't seem to find how to this.

**EDIT :**

Just found out a similar question had already been asked:
[Checking for the existence a reference/type at compile time in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953511/checking-for-the-existence-a-reference-type-at-compile-time-in-net)
(I had actually searched before posting, but somehow missed this)

But there doesn't seem to be a satisfying answer.

Is there really no way to do this?

**Edit2 :**
Sorry for not specifying this sooner,
but the code I wrote is for usage in a **Unity3D** project, it's a bunch of scripts basically.

Comment: So if you got the code in your App why rely on the existance of that lib in the first place?

Comment: @Stef check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/528492/how-can-i-check-if-a-library-dll-is-available-in-c is this what you are talking about?

Comment: Do I take it from the "Is there really no way to do this?" comment added after I posted an answer that this isn't the solution you are looking for? Any chance of some feedback as to why if that's the case? Thanks.

Comment: @David Arno, sorry, I posted that before I saw your answer. I'm having internet problems here and I lose connection all the time. I actually wrote that edit only a couple of seconds after I posted the question.

Comment: OK, cool. Sorry for being impatient :)

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume your project is called A:

1. Create a new project, B, and then add the sources files from A to B (see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saraford/archive/2008/11/26/did-you-know-how-to-add-a-linked-item-to-a-project-365.aspx) for details of how to do this.
2. In project A's properties, under Build add a Conditional compilation symbol, eg USE_LIBRARY.
3. For each source file that uses the library, modify the using statements to something like:

   #if USE_LIBRARY

   using Lib.Xxx

   #else

   using DummyLib.Xxx

   #endif

Then create DummyLib with the alternative code.

That way A.dll will be dependent on the library and B.dll won't be. You can then distribute B.dll without the library.

Comment: Thanks, but I think I should have been more thorough In my question.
The code I wrote are scripts in Unity3D, so I wouldn't know how to do this, or if it's even possible.

Comment: Which IDE do you use, or are you just using a text editor and compiling on the command line? The conditional compilation symbols and #if etc pre-process directives are features of the C# compiler, not just Visual Studio. So you could do the same as described above. How you'd do that depends on the OS, IDE etc you are using.

Comment: I use Visual Studio 2010 to write everything, but Unity compiles it all. (Unity is a game engine and editor).
The thing is, I wanted to be able to just share my scripts with others using Unity's Asset Store, but Unity does not allow sharing anything with that library I used, therefore I wanted those scripts to work regardless of whether that library exists (but still using it if it does). So I can't use your solution, as it just has to work by adding my scripts to a different project, without changing any project properties.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for your help, sorry I wasn't clear enough, I ended up using reflection to check if the library exists and to get the methods, which all works, but is unfortunately a lot slower
Also, sorry for the extremely late reply.

Comment: @Stef, no problems. Unfortunately I don't know anything about Unity, so I wouldn't have been much help in searching for a solution. Glad to hear you found a way of solving it, even if it isn't ideal.